# Can we add a tag for Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Would it be possible to add a tag for Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools, an open source GIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the [whitebox-gat](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whitebox-gat) tag to one [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/18568/753) that I found discussing it specifically, although there are other mentions of it on this site.

I have submitted a tag wiki entry based on its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitebox_Geospatial_Analysis_Tools) but you will not be able to see it until it is approved.

Comment: Thank you very much!